# How do I identify the object of a picture I've taken?

Tags: photo-management, curation, picture-samples, search

Sometimes I have a picture which I don't know, or which I have taken a long time ago. So how do you identify unknown stuff on your image?

For example I saw this picture, and what is the best approach to identify the hill on it?
[image]

Comment: Cool picture! I like it. :)

Comment: FWIW, that looks like Half-Dome at Yosemite.

Comment: I like how the hikers appear to be going straight up a sheer cliff.

Comment: @D. Lambert Thanks a lot, this seems to be correct!

Comment: @Craig Walk It does not only appear like this, but it is more or less straight up the sheer cliff. There are steel cables anchors which allows that.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: I hope nobody falls on that hike... they'd take out the whole convoy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have had some success posting pictures on Flickr asking for help identifying what it is, tagging with anything relevant possible.

Comment: +1 - Crowdsourcing your answer is probably the best bet.

Comment: yay for the masses! The only thing better than individuality is groupthink. Well, maybe. I mean what do you guys think?

Comment: @rfusca There is also a similar proposal on Area51 about reverse image search (http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26549/reverse-image-search). Maybe you're interested.

Comment: Wow! Awesome! I would really like to see that start. I even have a question ready!

Answer (score 12):

Try [Google Goggles](http://www.google.com/mobile/goggle) if your phone can do it. You take a picture and Google looks up what it is. You mileage may vary but it works for reasonably well known location even with not so direct framing.

Comment: I just tried google goggles on this image, and the result was Yosemite National Park... Did it get it right?? :)

Comment: I wonder if this uses some geographic information from your phone's location to "help it out"?

Comment: +1 Cool answer! I have tried google goggles but was a bit disappointed, then again, I took a photo of the Schrödinger equation... If this works out, that would be mighty useful!

Comment: @Roberto, yes Half Dome is in Yosemite.

Answer (score 8):

You could try using [TinEye Reverse Image Search](http://www.tineye.com/) to see if there are some similar pictures, perhaps those have some description nearby.

Comment: Didn't know about this, neeto!

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, it is nice. Unfortunately I could find a site with a descirption for the example image.

Answer (score 5):

Find out the capture date. Then check on shots you took before and after this one. Also be sure to look into your calendar/diary (if you have one) to see where you were at that time.

That's the only way I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

If the photo was [geotagged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geotagging), then at least you can find out *where* it was taken. That might be enough to help you identify the subject. (In this case, it almost certainly would, as it's a landscape shot).

Some cameras have GPS/geotagging built-in. Some can do it with an add-on module. If you have synchronized clocks and a standalone GPS, you can get software to match up your photos with your track, and apply geotags in post-production.