# Looking for info on photographer/camera settings for AppleTV Stock screensaver photos

Tags: metadata, camera-settings, stock-photography, photographers-rights

Is there a way to find out the lens and settings information for the default screen saver photos that come with the AppleTV?  Some of those pictures are quite interesting and I'd love to find out who, and with what gear shot them.

Comment: Seems to be very similar to: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170077/what-flickr-channel-is-apple-tv-using-as-its-default-screensaver

Comment: This would be a better question if you described the effect(s) you find interesting in the image(s) in question and asked how to recreate it. The particulars of a single image aren't likely to help many people, but a good question about achieving a certain look or effect will be useful for many people for years to com.

Comment: not about the effects.  I'd like to know who, and what lens.  The effect, I can guess.  Some of the shots look like they were suspended in mid-air (helicopter?).

Comment: If you look on the Apple website they might have information regarding who took the photo. You might then be able to find more details when you visit the Photographers site or alternatively contact them.

Answer (score 1):

Advice on getting image files out of Apple TV (so you could peek at their EXIF info directly) is clearly beyond scope of this site, but you could try your luck with taking a photo of the screen and then trying the techniques to  [identify image subject](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10966/4390/how-do-i-identify-the-object-of-a-picture-ive-taken) to find the image elsewhere.